# Linkedin oauth access token refresh does not increase expiration time

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using the following procedure to refresh linkedin oauth2 access tokens

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#refresh

After initiating the oauth procedure in the browser, the dialog is skipped as described, and a new code is issued which I then use to obtain a new, different access_token. However the `expires_in` field ( seconds till expiration ) is lesser than the one in the previous access_token it is in fact referencing the same expiration date.

This means that the expiration date effectively has not been extended, Which is the purpose of refreshing the access token.

Does refreshing an access token extend the expiration time ?
Or is there anything I am missing here ? 
( perhaps the expiration date can only be extended after a certain time of usage ? )

Answer (score -1):

The `expires_in` will always be the same as the previous `access_token` because `expires_in` is just the number of expires that the token will be valid for. I don't know what LinkedIn return for this value, but I'm guessing you are seeing a nice round number each time?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2

> expires_in
>
> ```
>      RECOMMENDED.  The lifetime in seconds of the access token.  For
>      example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will
>      expire in one hour from the time the response was generated.
>      If omitted, the authorization server SHOULD provide the
>      expiration time via other means or document the default value.
> ```

Comment: I am not seeing a round number, the number is decreasing in subsequent requests as it is referencing the same expiration date as the previous access token, as outlined in my question ( I edited the question to make that more clear tough )